# Given a matrix with random numbers in it , If a location has 1, make all the elements of that row and column as 1

Tags: algorithm, matrix

What could be the possible solution for this?
What I am thinking is, during first pass, I would note the rows and columns which have '1' in it.
Then I'd make 1 in every row and column for which row has 1.
And in 3rd pass, make 1 in every row and column for which column has 1.

This doesn't seem optimal. Anyone has better idea?

Answer (score 1):

Add a flag to every field in the matrix, indicating whether its value has been modified, initially set to `false`.

Scan the matrix, looking for entries where `value == 1 && flag == false`. Change all the elements in that row and column to 1, setting their flags to `true` if they didn't already contain 1.

As an additional optimization, you can have flags on the rows and columns, indicating whether they've already been updated from a previous element, so you don't bother updating them again.